# Docusign API, Remove ability to upload doc with sender view

Tags: docusignapi

Our application uses the Docusign API and the envelope is created programatically with all the recipients and pdfs added programatically as well. Our users are forwarded to the sender view URL to place signature tabs. That's all we really want them to do so we went into the preferences to "lock down" as much as we can so that the users can't modify recipients. That part worked.. if the sender is in the Docusign consule and clicks the button to try to modify the sender they can get into the window that you use to add/modify senders but it's greyed out which is perfect.

However, the senders appear to be able to still add extra documents to the envelope. Is there a setting in the new docusign experience or some kind of property in the API when creating the envelope or getting the sender view, that specifies that the sender should not be able to modify or add extra documents? In our application, there is no need for the sender to do this.

Comment: I don't think you can lock down the ability for sender to modify or add extra documents. Can you please share your usecase why you want to use embedded sender view? Why you can't add required DocuSign tabs directly on document using APIs?

Comment: My application is a web application. The senders have documents prepared for them that they need to send to someone else but all they need to do is place signature tabs. Our application decides exactly which documents need to be used, not the actual sender. We only want them to be able to place signature tabs and nothing more. Every document is different. There are no two that are alike so there's no way to predict where the signature tabs have to go. It 100% absolutely needs a human for them to look at the documents and determine where the tabs will go. It's ok if they delete, just cant add.

Comment: Got it. Do you own the document, or can you edit the document. If yes, then you can use Anchor String to place the DocuSign's Signature Tab.

Comment: If you put some white text on white label on a document then you can use Anchor String to tell DocuSign to put the tabs at the correct place. Also can you share how many documents you work with? Can those Documents be templatized in DocuSign?

Comment: No... *None* of these documents can be turned into templates and no we can't use Anchor Tags. Like I said.. there is NO way to tell ahead of time where the signature tabs need to be. Every document is unique. Some are generated. Some are scanned in from countless sources. It's 100% absolutely impossible. The *only* way to reliably know where the tabs are supposed to go are to have a human responsible for reviewing the docs placing the tabs... hence why we need the sender view. That's literally the ONLY thing senders use it for.

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution, you need to create a custom Permission Set for those senders who are not allowed to upload any document from their local machine.

[image]

Once such permission set is created then make this permission set for those type of senders. And when you are sending an envelope either you add them as "Allow To Edit" recipient that way they will be able to edit the envelope by changing the tags etc but cannot upload document from their local machine.

Comment: I tried this out, but it turns out there's an issue: I wasn't able to programmatically add the ORIGINAL document via the API when creating the envelope when I had this "disable document upload" checked. Apparently it doesn't just disable the ability to upload a new document in the sender view, but disabled the ability to even add any documents in the API..

Comment: I guess I could set up a SECOND account, and create a permission set with this upload ability disabled. And then I would have to use a combination of two accounts... I would create the envelope and programmatically add the initial document with the one account with full permissions and then when getting the sender view, use the second account. I'll give that I try I suppose and let you know

Comment: One solution is, You need to use two users in same DocuSign account, first user should have full permission set and other user's access would be limited. Its called SOBO in DocuSign world, X-DocuSign-Authentication:{"Username": "fullAccessUser@email.com", "Password":"FullAccessUserPassword", "IntegratorKey":"16f81d9e-e9ee-408d-bc60-d6e1aecd9757", "SendOnBehalfOf":"LimitedUserEmail"}, then DocuSign will allow you to send document via API but sender (i.e limited user) will not be able to add any document.

Comment: Second solution, is as I suggested in my post to use "Allow To Edit" recipient type. Send an envelope from user who has full access and add limited user as first recipient with recipientType as "Allow To Edit". RecipientType will be able to update the envelope but since he has no upload access so cannot add any new document.

Comment: I can programmatically allow a sender to "Allow to Edit" from the API?

Comment: Yes, definitely, instead of "signers" node you need to add "editors" node as documented here, [Editor] (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create/#/definitions/editor)